# HTML Chat - position div relative to window

Tags: html, css

I have a chat html, and I have put some stuff inside a div. I activated scroll on overflow-y, and this is working. The problem is that I need a text box down that doesn't move on screen.

I want it to look like a chat window, the div fixed on screen, with the text-box down. The problem is that, the div stretches within its contents, causing the screen to overflow and show the scrollbar. this way, the text-box isn't always visible.

EDIT: Updated the typos (added px, and 100% to content div as it should be) and also, the inner scrollbar isn't working, and the roomname div is in front of the content div, this way, we can't see what's written on it.

```css
div#roomnamediv{
 font-family:courier;
 text-align:center;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 height:30; width:100%;
 display:block;
  background-color:#111;
}

div#content-wrapper{
 margin-top:-10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 display:block;
 height:100%;
}

div#content{
 
 display:block;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height:100%;
}

div#text-send{
 
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 display:block;
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
 
 bottom:0;
 position:fixed;
}

input#sendtxt{
 
 width:100%;
 font-family:courier;
 padding:10px;
 border:none;
 display:block; 
 outline:none;
 
 
 bottom:0;
}

body {

font-family: Courier;
font-width:23px;
padding:0;

}

div.sb-ymes {

display:block;
margin:10 10 10 auto;
padding:10;
max-width:70%;
}

div.sb-tmes {

left:0;
display:block;
margin:10 10 auto 10;
padding:10;
max-width:70%;
}

font.alias {

font-size:12;
display:block;
margin-bottom:5;

}

div.system {

display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:10;
max-width:500;
text-align:center;
}
div.sb-tmes {
 
background-color:#444;

}

body {
 
background-color:#111; 
color:white;
}

div#content {
 
 background-color:#222;
}

div.sb-ymes{
 
background-color:#555;

}

input#sendtxt{
 
background-color:#333;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="theme-dark.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Speech Bubble Chat [Test]</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div id="roomnamediv">
   <h3 id="roomname">Henri's Office</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="content-wrapper"><div id="content">
  
   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
   <span>Howdy, Henri... What IS this thing we are using right now...?
   
   </span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-ymes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
   <span>This is an awesome new Chat i am planning to make on the future.</span>
   <i class="em em-heart"></i>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
   <span>GREAT! Can I have some... new friends???</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-ymes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
   <span>Surely.<br><br>Also, I think you should socialize more with the other robots of Bitwin. Such as the Speech Bubble bots. Its... not officializated yet.<br><br>But it would be cool... wouldn't it? Also, I'll add someone new...!</span>
   </div>

   <div class="system">
   <span><b>Hohen-senpai</b> joined the room.</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
   <span>Oh! Hello master Vitor. How are Akimaru-sama, and the others going?</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
   <span>They're fine. Reisuke just had a child with Rioku. His name is <i>Azariel Lucifer.</i></span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-ymes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
   <span>Whaaaaaaaaaat? With... RIOKU?! That's... very cool.<br><br>I think they both need a break after everything that happened. Good he will have a chance to be happy and have a family.</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
   <span>Rioku hates him. Azariel hates him too.</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-ymes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
   <span>Oh... that makes more sense.</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
   <span>It's all right. He's still happy, anyways.</span>
   </div>
      
      
  <br><br><br><br></div></div>
  
  <div id="text-send">
  <input id="sendtxt" type="text" />
  <div/>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it a typo: `div#textsend` should be `div#text-send`

Answer (score 0):

Use the css below for your div, you need to give `bottom:0` as well to your `position:fixed`

```
<div id="textsend">
    <input id="sendtxt" type="text" />
<div/>
```

Css:

```
div#textsend{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

You should also reorder your css and remove the typos as well. Use px while providing paddings and margin when its not `0`.

```css
body {
 
background-color:#111; 
color:white;
}

div#content{
 
 display:block;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

div#textsend{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

input#sendtxt{
 
 width:100%;
 margin-top:10px;
 font-family: Courier;
 padding:10px;
 border:none;
 display:block; 
 outline:none;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}

div.sb-tmes {
 
background-color:#444;

}

div#content {
 
 background-color:#222;
}

div.sb-ymes{
 
background-color:#555;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Speech Bubble Chat [Test]</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="content">
  
   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
   <span>Howdy, Henri... What IS this thing we are using right now...?
   
   </span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-ymes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
   <span>This is an awesome new Chat i am planning to make on the future.</span>
   <i class="em em-heart"></i>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
   <span>GREAT! Can I have some... new friends???</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-ymes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
   <span>Surely.<br><br>Also, I think you should socialize more with the other robots of Bitwin. Such as the Speech Bubble bots. Its... not officializated yet.<br><br>But it would be cool... wouldn't it? Also, I'll add someone new...!</span>
   </div>

   <div class="system">
   <span><b>Hohen-senpai</b> joined the room.</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
   <span>Oh! Hello master Vitor. How are Akimaru-sama, and the others going?</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
   <span>They're fine. Reisuke just had a child with Rioku. His name is <i>Azariel Lucifer.</i></span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-ymes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
   <span>Whaaaaaaaaaat? With... RIOKU?! That's... very cool.<br><br>I think they both need a break after everything that happened. Good he will have a chance to be happy and have a family.</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
   <span>Rioku hates him. Azariel hates him too.</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-ymes">
   <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
   <span>Oh... that makes more sense.</span>
   </div>

   <div class="sb-tmes">
   <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
   <span>It's all right. He's still happy, anyways.</span>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div id="textsend">
  <input id="sendtxt" type="text" />
  <div/>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for replying, but, i also need the body not to scroll (and use only the scrollbar of the CONTENT div...)

Comment: use auto for `overflow-y:auto`, so the body will  work for the scrolling part, updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

It already almost works. You're missing "px" after some of your style rules in your CSS. For example:

```
div#textsend {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px; /* add 'px' or '%' or some measurement after all numbers except 0 */
  width: 100%;
}
```

You also need to set a height to the 'chat' window in order for it to scroll. See fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/skkq2308/

Comment: I already updated this... and it doesn't change very much... i have also set the content div height to 100%. but it takes 100% of the window size, not 100% of its available space. what causes the body to overflow...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) for the page layout.

> CSS Flexible Box Layout is a module of CSS that defines a CSS box model optimized for user interface design. In the flex layout model, the children of a flex container can be laid out in any direction, and can “flex” their sizes, either growing to fill unused space or shrinking to avoid overflowing the parent.

It might help simplify your layout to these basics:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#chatbox {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

---

Here's an example:

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  background-color: black;
  color: gray;
  padding: .5em 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#chatbox {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: black;
}

#prompt input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
}


.chat_entry {
  padding: .5em .25em;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}
.chat_entry:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #666;
}

.system {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>

<div id="chatbox">

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;ADMIN&gt; </font>
    <span>FIRST ENTRY.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
    <span>Howdy, Henri... What IS this thing we are usin</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
    <span>This is an awesome new Chat i am planning to make on the future.</span>
    <i class="em em-heart"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
    <span>GREAT! Can I have some... new friends???</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
    <span>Surely.<br><br>Also, I think you should socialize more with the other robots of Bitwin. Such as the Speech Bubble bots. Its... not officializated yet.<br><br>But it would be cool... wouldn't it? Also, I'll add someone new...!</span>
  </div>

  <div class="system">
    <span><b>Hohen-senpai</b> joined the room.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
    <span>Oh! Hello master Vitor. How are Akimaru-sama, and the others going?</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
    <span>They're fine. Reisuke just had a child with Rioku. His name is <i>Azariel Lucifer.</i></span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
    <span>Whaaaaaaaaaat? With... RIOKU?! That's... very cool.<br><br>I think they both need a break after everything that happened. Good he will have a chance to be happy and have a family.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
    <span>Rioku hates him. Azariel hates him too.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
    <span>Oh... that makes more sense.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
    <span>It's all right. He's still happy, anyways.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
    <span>Howdy, Henri... What IS this thing we are usin</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
    <span>This is an awesome new Chat i am planning to make on the future.</span>
    <i class="em em-heart"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
    <span>GREAT! Can I have some... new friends???</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
    <span>Surely.<br><br>Also, I think you should socialize more with the other robots of Bitwin. Such as the Speech Bubble bots. Its... not officializated yet.<br><br>But it would be cool... wouldn't it? Also, I'll add someone new...!</span>
  </div>

  <div class="system">
    <span><b>Hohen-senpai</b> joined the room.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0cc">&lt;LUSY&gt; </font>
    <span>Oh! Hello master Vitor. How are Akimaru-sama, and the others going?</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
    <span>They're fine. Reisuke just had a child with Rioku. His name is <i>Azariel Lucifer.</i></span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
    <span>Whaaaaaaaaaat? With... RIOKU?! That's... very cool.<br><br>I think they both need a break after everything that happened. Good he will have a chance to be happy and have a family.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
    <span>Rioku hates him. Azariel hates him too.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#0ff">&lt;Henri&gt; </font>
    <span>Oh... that makes more sense.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;Hohen-senpai&gt; </font>
    <span>It's all right. He's still happy, anyways.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="chat_entry">
    <font class="alias" color="#af0">&lt;ADMIN&gt; </font>
    <span>LAST ENTRY.</span>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="prompt">
  <input type="text" placeholder="TYPE HERE">
</div>
```